# how to contruct this loop in jinja2 template

Tags: loops, templates, jinja2, ansible

I have a following ansible task

```
---
- name: Add inventory hosts to hosts file
  template: src=hosts.j2 dest=/etc/hosts owner=root group=root mode=0644
  with_dict: hosts
```

and the jinja template looks like this

```
{% for host in hosts %}

{{ host }}{% for domain in item.value.domains %} {{ host }}.{{ domain }}{% endfor %}{% if item.value.alias is defined %}{% for domain in item.value.domains %} {{ item.value.alias }}.{{ domain }}{% endfor %}{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

where the hosts dict is

hosts:

```
  'server1':
    domains:
      - 'com'
      - 'net'
    alias: 'opendj'
  'server2':
    domains:
      - 'org'
    alias: 'metadata'
```

and I get

```
server1 server1.org metadata.org
server2 server2.org metadata.org
```

What should I do to achieve correct state i.e.

```
server1 server1.com server1.net opendj.com opendj.net
server2 server2.org metadata.org
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it will do what you want:

```
{% for host in hosts %}
{{ host }} {% for d in hosts[host]['domains'] %} {{ host }}.{{ d }}{% endfor %} {% for d in hosts[host]['domains'] %} {{ hosts[host]['alias'] }}.{{ d }}{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Or, if you want a slightly prettier version:

```
{% for host in hosts %}
{{ host -}}
{% for d in hosts[host]['domains'] %} {{ host }}.{{ d }}{% endfor -%}
{% for d in hosts[host]['domains'] %} {{ hosts[host]['alias'] }}.{{ d }}{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The `-` at the end of the `{{ host -}}` and `{% endfor -%}` statements will suppress the trailing newline that would otherise occur in those locations.

And if you want to only print out aliases if `alias` is defined:

```
{% for host in hosts %}
{{ host -}}
{% for d in hosts[host]['domains'] %} {{ host }}.{{ d }}{% endfor -%}
{% if hosts[host]['alias'] is defined %}
{% for d in hosts[host]['domains'] %} {{ hosts[host]['alias'] }}.{{ d }}{% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```